# How to find the maximum value of a numpy array between given indicies?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have loaded some data from a csv using numpy.genfromtxt.

This gives me an array(n,3) where n can be upto ~500000.

I want to find the maximum value in any of the three columns between values of n=n1 and n=n2.

In Matlab I'd be fine, but Python is a new beast!

(New to Python, using Spyder & Anaconda.)

Comment: doesn't `np.max(a, axis=1)` give you this?

Comment: That (I believe) is returning the max of the whole array, not between n=n1 and n=n2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

numpy arrays have [`max`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html#numpy-ndarray-max) method. For example

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(30).reshape((10, 3))
n1, n2 = 2, 5
max_value = data[n1:n2, :].max()
```

`max_value` is `14`.

If you want to find the maximum values for each column:

```
max_values = data[n1:n2, :].max(axis=0)
```

in this case `max_values` is `array([12, 13, 14])`

Comment: I know it's tempting to use 1d slicing if you just want to slice the first dimension of a multidimensional array but I would always recommend explicitly not slicing the other dimension(-s) ``[n1:n2, :]`` that makes it more readable/understandable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done.  I'd be glad of feedback - it feels like it should be a one-liner:

```
M=numpy.max(a[n1:n2,:],axis=0)
M=numpy.max(M)
```

Comment: If you avoid the `axis=0` the result should be fine. The maximum amongst the maximum of numbers is redundant.